# What is the best way to setup default snippets in Wagtail

Tags: django-models, wagtail, wagtail-snippet

I would like to setup default snippets (article categories) in a Wagtail blog project.

My option would be to add the following line at the end of the **models.py** module:

```py
if BlogPageCategory.objects.filter(name = 'Association').count() == 0:
    category = BlogPageCategory(name='Association')
    category.save()
```

Is it the best way to do it? Would it have any impact on the site performance?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve what you want:

- The recommended way to do this is using [Data migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/migrations/#data-migrations). The advantage of this method is that setting defaults in your database will be done when initializing, instead of a runtime action.
- The way you described (Although it'd be best to do this in your `AppConfig's` `ready()` method (as described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.ready)), as that is most commonly the place to run any code upon server startup. It won't have a very big impact on performance, because it is only run once (When your server is started)
- Using fixtures, which IMO is only necessary when loading large amounts of data into your database.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, the first option seems to be the best way.